# How do I multiply 2 cols from 2 tables for 2 different conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables Table A (6 columns 100 rows) and Table B (6 columns 2 rows).

`Table A` contains the following columns:

- Name: same for all rows
- Date: chronological dates
- V1,V2,V3,V4: 4 columns with numerical values

`Table B` contains the following columns:

- Name: same as table A
- Model: 2 different values
- V1,V2,V3,V4 : 4 columns with numerical values (values of table A and tableB not same)

**TableA:**

```
+------+----------+----+----+----+----+
| Name |   Date   | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
+------+----------+----+----+----+----+
| abc  | 1/12020  |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
| abc  | 2/1/2020 |  2 |  3 |  5 |  1 |
| abc  | 3/1/2020 |  1 |  4 |  2 |  1 |
+------+----------+----+----+----+----+
```

**Table B:**

```
+------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| Name | Model | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
+------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| abc  | AA    |  2 |  3 |  1 |  4 |
| abc  | BB    |  1 |  3 |  4 |  5 |
+------+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

I need to multiply V1, V2, V3, V4 values of Table B with the same from Table A and create a new table, Table C, where Name, Date, Model, V1, V2, V3, V4 values will be there.

For each date there will be 2 model rows with multiplication results of V1*V1, V2*V2, V3*V3, V4*V4. The result will look like below:

**Table C:**

```
+------+----------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| Name |   Date   | Model | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
+------+----------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| abc  | 1/1/2020 | AA    |  2 |  6 |  3 | 16 |
| abc  | 1/1/2020 | BB    |  1 |  6 | 12 | 20 |
| abc  | 2/1/2020 | AA    |  4 |  9 |  5 |  4 |
| abc  | 2/1/2020 | BB    |  2 |  9 | 20 |  5 |
| abc  | 3/1/2020 | AA    |  2 | 12 |  2 |  4 |
| abc  | 3/1/2020 | BB    |  1 | 12 |  8 |  5 |
+------+----------+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Is this not just a straight `JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`? What do you have so far?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but left join us not giving the expected result only name and date column is getting populated other columns are only resulting NULL values in all the rows

Comment: I don't see a `left join` above, where is the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- Mock-up Data --
DECLARE @TableA table (
    [Name] varchar(10), [Date] date, V1 int, V2 int, V3 int, V4 int
);
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
    ( 'abc', '01/01/2020', 1, 2, 3, 4 ),
    ( 'abc', '02/01/2020', 2, 3, 5, 1 ),
    ( 'abc', '03/01/2020', 1, 4, 2, 1 );

DECLARE @TableB table (
    [Name] varchar(10), Model varchar(2), V1 int, V2 int, V3 int, V4 int
);
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES
    ( 'abc', 'AA', 2, 3, 1, 4 ),
    ( 'abc', 'BB', 1, 3, 4, 5 );

-- Get resultset --

SELECT
    a.[Name], a.[Date], b.Model
    , b.V1 * a.V1 AS V1
    , b.V2 * a.V2 AS V2
    , b.V3 * a.V3 AS V3
    , b.V4 * a.V4 AS V4
FROM @TableA a
LEFT JOIN @TableB b
    ON a.[Name] = b.[Name];
```

Returns

```
+------+------------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| Name |    Date    | Model | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
+------+------------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| abc  | 2020-01-01 | AA    |  2 |  6 |  3 | 16 |
| abc  | 2020-01-01 | BB    |  1 |  6 | 12 | 20 |
| abc  | 2020-02-01 | AA    |  4 |  9 |  5 |  4 |
| abc  | 2020-02-01 | BB    |  2 |  9 | 20 |  5 |
| abc  | 2020-03-01 | AA    |  2 | 12 |  2 |  4 |
| abc  | 2020-03-01 | BB    |  1 | 12 |  8 |  5 |
+------+------------+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

**Note:**

I'm sure you know this, however, the `LEFT JOIN` ensures all data from `TableA` is returned regardless of a match in `TableB`. Also, while I didn't do it here, you will probably want to add an `ORDER BY`.